# How to disable the web-cam in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, webcam

My laptop has a built-in web-cam. I never use it. And I've read about how hackers (from the deep web which I use sometimes) hack it and then they can see you and spy on you. So, how can I make the cam stop working? I've already put a sticker on it but I was wondering if they can track my location from it.

Comment: If hackers have broken in to your computer, they can't get your location from a webcam that has tape over it. However they may certainly be able to get location information from elsewhere in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've already put a sticker on it but I was wondering if they can track my location from it.

No.

A camera is a camera. It captures video (light). Sometimes, cameras have an attached microphone (though on a laptop it's usually separate). Those capture audio.

They can not "track [your] location" in any other way short of identifying features in captured video (which you've blocked) or audio. A webcam does not include any radio hardware.

---

Web browsers (Firefox, Chrome) already do not allow access to any recording devices (both video and audio) without explicit authorisation. If your concern is that they'll somehow bypass these browser protection mechanisms, then any other software method of disabling these devices is similarly pointless.

If you really want to, you can disable the device in Device Manager. Of course, anyone with admin access can go and enable it again.

---

Now, you might want to block the microphone (audio). Unfortunately, this isn't quite as easy as a piece of tape. If you're willing to accept a permanent solution, filling the hole with glue should more or less do the job.